# WPF - Grid - updating Row and Column number attached properties on child controls each time a new Row/Column is adeed removed

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, grid

I have a WPF Grid with a XAML similar to this:

```
  <Grid width=200 Height=200 >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >                             
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="24" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
      <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

      <TextBlock Text="Age" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
      <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

  </Grid>
```

I need to add a new row in between existing 2 rows of data, but my worry is that when I add a new row, I will need to manually update Grid.Row attached property in each of the controls that appear in rows below the newly added row.

Is there a smarter way of doing this? may be to set Row/Column numbers relative to adjacent Rows/Columns ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been addressed in the Visual Studio 2010 through the Design-Time Row and Column Manipulation Features.

Not needed to manually update Row and Column numbers manually any more as this is taken care of by Visual Studio.

Below demo illustrates this nicely.

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/layout,-rendering,-and-panels/grid-control-design-time-row-and-column-manipulation-features

Answer (score 3):

You cannot achieve this automatically. You have to manually adjust the value of Grid.Row for every child of the grid, as necessary:

```
foreach (UIElement child in grid.Children)
            if (Grid.GetRow(child) >= indexOfNewRow)
                Grid.SetRow(Grid.GetRow(child) + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Andy.

based on your code snippet, wondering whether you assumed that I was adding new rows programatically?

I meant to do this on XAML.. and was trying to find whether there's a way to specify Row and Column numbers relative to adjacant Rows/Columns

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer in [MSDN Silverlight Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/de-DE/0dc73921-c1bd-465e-b584-c14d7863fa73/xaml-designer-for-doing-inserting-rowscolumns-to-a-grid-layout-control-in-sl-4-5?forum=silverlightdevtools) from Jason Rosenthal:

> If you hover over the left or top edge of the grid, a tiny dropdown
>   arrow will popup with the options moved to there

Answer (score 0):

The link on the accepted answer now points to a general Silverlight 5 page.

You can do this is the Visual Studio XAML designer, which I illustrate with screen shots below. This works for both WPF and Silverlight.

It's best to zoom the 'Design' view so you can see more clearly.

Then, hover the mouse cursor on the left-hand edge, and you will get the insert cursor with horizontal orange line indicating where the row will be inserted:

[image: XAML Design]

XAML before:

[image: XAML Before]

XAML after insert:

[image: XAML After Insert]

Notice that all the Grid.Row numbers after the insert point have automatically incremented. The row at the insert point has been automatically split into two, and Grid.RowSpan added to the item that was in the row at the insert point.

In more complicated layouts the auto-insert may incorrectly add or change the Margins of items below the insert point, so watch carefully for this.